# Why did I get two Ubuntu One cloud icons in the tray after the 13.04 upgrade?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-one, icons, system-tray

I upgraded to 13.04, but now I have two Ubuntu One cloud icons in my tray. Can someone explain why and help me remove one of them?

See [image: this image]  what I mean?

EDIT: The difference isn't so clear as "general U1 vs. U1Music" for me, but even if it were, why does that require two identical icons? Here are the menu items for my two icons:

First:

- Open Ubuntu One Folder
- Launch Ubuntu One Website
- (greyed out) Synchronization complete
- (greyed out) Your files are up to date
- (greyed out) Free space: 24.9 GiB
- Open Control Panel
- (greyed out) Recently Published Files
- Disconnect

Second:

- Ubuntu One (with an On/Off toggle switch)
- Open Ubuntu One
- Open the Ubuntu One Folder
- Share a File
- Go to the Ubuntu One Website
- Current and Recent Transfers
- Get More Space
- Get Help on the Web

Comment: One is the ubuntu one music and the other is ubuntu one. This what is see in the launcher after upgrading to 13.04

Comment: @Raghunandan: That does not appear to be the case for me. Please see the update I made to the question listing the two different menus, whose items greatly overlap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the old `indicator-ubuntuone` package and the new `indicator-sync` as well. Remove the `indicator-ubuntuone` package by running `sudo apt-get purge indicator-ubuntuone` and restart your session, to have it go away.

The `indicator-sync` is the new system synchronization indicator, and the only officially supported indicator for Ubuntu One.

Comment: FYI the application to remove was indicator-ubuntuone, not ubuntuone-indicator on my system.

Answer (score 1):

The command stated above did not work for me. [I posted a question myself about this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309885/two-ubuntu-one-cloud-icons-in-the-top-bar) (hyperlinked for details), but I ended up finding the answer by myself. Here I'll post the command that worked for me, leaving only the NEW Ubuntu One icon up there:

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-ubuntuone
```

Comment: That is the same command that is in the other answer. The package name was wrong (as the indicator-ubuntuone package was renamed from ubuntuone-indicator at some poing). The answer has been edited to have the correct package name.